# Simplifying a trigonometric expression: $\frac{2 \tan⁡64°}{1-\tan^2⁡64°}$

Tags: trigonometry

I want to simply the following without use of a calculator: $\displaystyle \frac{2 \tan⁡64°}{1-\tan^2⁡64°}$

At first I thought that this is tangent double angle identity = $\tan(2\times 64°)  $

hence $=\tan(128°) $

Is that all? Really?

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle Yup,\ that's\ it.$

Comment: Double play here!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct, $$
\frac{2 \tan⁡x}{1-\tan^2x} = \tan 2x.
$$ The given problem is absolutely in the given format. Therefore, you directly use this principle to get the required solution that you have already got.